# SQLite - Get all hours from date range

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite query that lists all days between two dates. I want to achieve the same with the hours from those days.

This is my current query to get all days between two dates

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(starttime) AS
(VALUES(min(starttime))
UNION ALL SELECT date(starttime, '+1 day')
FROM v_sessions
WHERE endtime <= max(startTime))
SELECT Date(starttime) AS Date
FROM v_sessions
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY date
```

Output

---

```
Date
2018-10-21
2018-10-22
2018-10-23
2018-10-24
2018-10-25
2018-10-26
2018-10-27
2018-10-28
2018-10-29
2018-10-30
2018-10-31
```

This is the desired result of a modified query.

```
__________
Date
2018-10-19 01:00:00
2018-10-19 02:00:00
2018-10-19 03:00:00
2018-10-19 04:00:00
2018-10-19 05:00:00
2018-10-19 06:00:00
…..
2018-10-19 23:00:00
2018-10-20 00:00:00
2018-10-20 01:00:00
2018-10-20 02:00:00
…
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to use `datetime` instead of `date`.

The crux will be to change this `date(starttime, '+1 day')` to this `datetime(starttime, '+1 hour')`. You could use start:  `datetime(starttime,'start of day')` and end: `datetime(endtime, 'start of day','+23 hours')` if you want all the hours in the specific dates, or some other date arithmetic if starttime and endtime include specific limiting hours.

Comment: Thanks Dino! I decided to solved this via C# that I am using for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to solve this via C# that I am using for my use case.

```
           using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = data\\Reporting.db; Version = 3;"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = queryString;
                        while (startDateTime <= endDateTime)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$date", startDateTime);

                            maxConcurrentSessions.Rows.Add(startDateTime, Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));

                            startDateTime = startDateTime.AddHours(1);
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
```